# How do I increase the mouse sensitivity in X3: Albion Prelude?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I just started X3: Albion Prelude and the mouse cursor is just far too slow. I have to move the mouse across almost the complete mouse pad to get from one end of the screen to the other side.

My Windows mouse acceleration setting is already almost at the maximum, and I found no setting inside X3 that I could adjust.

Is there any way I can make the mouse faster inside X3?

Comment: try enabling vsync?  X3 doesn't have in game mouse settings afaik

Answer (score -1):

Vsync didn't help me.

Try re-installing your mousedriver; that sped up my good old Logitech RX1000 a lot!